# Cakephp errors relating to findAll() and foreach()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have just completed this tutorial from http://www.sitepoint.com/application-development-cakephp/ as I start my first cakephp project on monday, and I am getting a number of errors and warnings relating to `findAll()` and `foreach()`.

Here are the errors:

```
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'findAll' at line 1 [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 684].
```

and

```
Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP\views\notes\index.ctp, line 11].
```

Here is the controller:

```
    function index(){
        $this->set('notes', $this->Note->findAll());
    }

    function view($id){
        $this->Note->id = $id;
        $this->set('data', $this->Note->read());
    }

    function add(){
        if (!empty($this->data['Note']))
        {
            if($this->Note->save($this->data['Note'])){
                $this->flash('Your note has been updated.','/notes/');
            }
        }
    }

    function edit($id = null){
        if (empty($this->data['Note'])){
            $this->Note->id = $id;
            $this->data = $this->Note->read();
        }
        else{
            if($this->Note->save($this->data['Note']))
            {
                $this->flash('Your note has been updated.','/notes/');
            }
        }
    }

    function delete($id){
        if ($this->Note->del($id)){
            $this->flash('The note with id: '.$id.' has been deleted.', '/notes');
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Here is index.ctp:

```
<h1>My Notes</h1>  
    <p>  
    <?php echo $html->link('Add Note', '/notes/add') ?>  
    </p>  
    <table>  
    <tr>  
        <th>Id</th>  
        <th>Title</th>  
        <th>Created</th>  
    </tr>  
    <?php foreach ($notes as $note): ?>  
    <tr>  
        <td><?php echo $note['Note']['id']; ?></td>  
        <td>  
            <?php echo $html->link($note['Note']['title'], "/notes/view/{$note['Note']['id']}")?>  
        [<?php echo $html->link('Edit', "/notes/edit/{$note['Note']['id']}")?>,  
        <?php echo $html->link('Delete', "/notes/delete/{$note['Note']['id']}", null, 'Are you sure?')?>]  
        </td>  

        <td><?php echo $note['Note']['created']; ?></td>  
    </tr>  
    <?php endforeach; ?>  
    </table>
```

And here is the database.php file that is in use:

```
var $default = array(
    'driver'   => 'mysql',
    'connect'  => 'mysql_pconnect',
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'login'    => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'memo'
    );
```

All supplied code is taken from the tutorial at http://www.sitepoint.com/application-development-cakephp/ .

QUESTION:
Why is this not working?
I am using Cakephp 1.3.10.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using Cake 1.1 syntax while running 1.3. The article is about 5 years old!

If I remember correctly, 1.1 had a findAll() method but was deprecated in favour of the new syntax. Cake 1.3 actually uses the below syntax

```
$this->Note->find('all')
```

Manual : http://book.cakephp.org/view/1021/find-all

The reason you're getting the second error is that `foreach` is trying to loop through something that is not an array (your `findAll` call probably returns undefined.).

Cake still had the `findAllBy<field>` syntax, but this is not what you need right now.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1025/findAllBy

You might also want to look at the blog application tutorial : http://book.cakephp.org/view/1528/Blog

It covers a lot of the basics and should give you enough of a primer to start with Cae.